# SharePoint workflow task not created

Tags: workflow

I have a custom workflow which starts an approval workflow whenever a list item is created. On our test server, this work fine. However, when I deployed on another server, the task of the approval workflow is not being created. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have activated the feature to view the workflow or not? If yes check workflow setting whether it is referring to the same task list or not.